# how to use custom rule in middleware of laravel 9.x?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

**NOTE: this is for an endpoint. not for a form request.**

let's say I have middleware named Inputs which has this code in the handle()

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {

  $data = $request->all();
   
  foreach ($data as $array) {
      //HOW TO USE THE CUSTOM RULE HERE?
  }
  return next($request);

}
```

here's the custom rule `App\Rules`

```
class MyRule {


  public function construct() {}

  public function passes($attribute, $value) {
       if ($value > 1) {
          return false;
       }
      return true;
  }

  public function message() {
      return "data invalid";
  }

}
```

Comment: I would probably suggest using your rules in a [form request](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation) instead of placing it middleware

Comment: this is not for a form request, it's for an endpoint trying to validate the request

Comment: Rules are intended to be used with validation. If you don't intend to use a normal validation process then maybe just write a custom function that does what you need i.e. you'd need to do `$request->validate([ 'key' => new MyRule() ])` or something like that

Comment: Ignore the naming of Laravels Form Request Class, they can be and are used for API endpoints too. They can be used anywhere as a replacement for the standard Laravel Request Class.